# Are there scientifically grounded alternatives to analytical psychotherapy?

Tags: psychoanalysis, therapy

I'm a physicist and am interested in exploring taking therapies to help me overcome anxieties and other issues that I have that seem to me to be psychologically founded. Anecdotally, a few people close to me have been in therapy over the years and have strongly advocated its efficacy. However, and equally, someone close to me tried therapy and found it useless. Moreover, as a scientist I am deeply sceptical of psychoanalysis as a theory and therefore quite adverse to contributing to its continuation.

So, are there alternative therapeutic techniques I could consider that have a more objective, scientific grounding? Or, am I simply wrong headed and modern psychoanalysis has evolved to the extent that it can be considered objective and scientific?

Comment: Yes. see https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/4469/how-effective-is-cognitive-behavioral-therapy-for-anxiety-disorders

Comment: @Fizz - There has been a lot of articles stating that CBT is very effective, and there are articles which have stated that it is not as effective as has been claimed. See https://psychology.stackexchange.com/a/17325

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE! [For a number of reasons outlined in this meta post](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/502/why-was-my-self-help-question-closed-as-off-topic) we can not, and will not, give advice or potential diagnoses for any specific individual. If you have a question regarding your mental health, you should see a doctor. For further information on how this site is supposed to work, what is on-topic or not, you can take the [tour], visit the [ask] page and [meta].

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/9929/7001

Comment: @ArnonWeinberg - The question may be a duplicate of the one you linked to in some respects, but due to the fact that there are questions surrounding the efficacy of CBT, as highlighted in [my answer to the question on Cognitive-Behavioral Therapy Limitations](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/a/17325) which I linked to in an earlier comment, it would be good to re-open the question by asking another one along the lines of this one.  However, with the personal nature of the question, that makes it off-topic for that reason.

Comment: Since we are closing this question anyway, I'm going to mark it as a duplicate so that at least future visitors can find a relevant answer.  @ChrisRogers I think your comment is equally relevant for the other question, and as I am also skeptical about CBT, I've added a link to your answer there.